# How to build a ProgressBar in Nextjs in the new App Router?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, app-router

I've been trying to create a progress bar for project i'm working on but the `ProgressBar` Library from Npm seems to not work with the new `App` Router.

Any Ideas on how to implement this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-nprogress-bar

It works for both `app` and `pages` router.

Answer (score 0):

I found npm package named "next-nprogress-bar" is quite good. It can be used with nextjs pages and app router both. I have used it with App router and it works fine.

Tested with nextjs latest version 13.5.3.